# Spring multiple authentication methods for different api endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, x509

I want to check for different authentication methods for different endpoints. Methods i want to use are x509 and jwt. I need to use **only** x509 for certain endpoint and use JWT for all other requests.

Here's my web security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/transaction/testf").authenticated().and()
                .x509()
                .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
                .userDetailsService(new X509UserDetailsService())
                ;
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class ApiTokenSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token", "/api/dealer/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                ;
        }

    }
}
```

This configuration only checks */api/transaction/testf* endpoint for x509 certificate and allows all other endpoints to respond. I need other endpoints to return 503 without a jwt token.

Comment: For each filter chain, you must specify the ant pattern for that chain.
`http.antMatcher` (not http.authorizeRequests as the first call)
This post describes what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657163/springsecurity-make-restful-api-basic-auth-authentication-possible-via-only-a-s/54658476#54658476

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have two filter chains. Neither of them have an entry point pattern properly configured `http.antMatcher`. That means they are configured to use `/**` as their entry point pattern.

For example

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
```

is the same thing as saying:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
```

What we are saying here is

1. `http` - the security filter chain
2. `http.antMatcher` - the entry point to the security filter chain
3. `http.authorizeRequests` - start of my endpoint access restrictions
4. `http.authorizeRequests.antMatchers` - list of URLs with specific access

So what you need to do is change your `@Order(1)` filter chain to narrow down the pattern. For example: `http.antMatcher("/api/transaction/**")`

Your configuration will now look like

```java
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/transaction/**") //customized entry point
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/transaction/testf").authenticated().and()
                .x509()
                .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
                .userDetailsService(new X509UserDetailsService())
                ;
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class ApiTokenSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/**") //this is default
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token", "/api/dealer/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                ;
        }
```

With your existing configuration the filter chain named `ApiWebSecurityConfig` will trap all calls. The other filter chain, `ApiTokenSecurityConfig`, is never used.

Comment: the last link for "spring security: make restful api.." is broken.

Comment: what I have to change if I need only jwt for one endpoint and only x509 for the other ?

Answer (score 4):

Since `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is `@Deprecated`, preferable use multiple `SecurityFilterChain` (see [updated Multiple HttpSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity)):

```
@Bean
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/api/**")                                   
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean                                                            
    public SecurityFilterChain formLoginFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

Comment: This is not working for me. The second filter chain is not running.. If I change the @Order to the other it runs so the filter is correct.  Any idea why it might not be running the second filter?

Comment: Found it. It was the             .antMatcher("/api/**") in the first one that was missing