# How to add two context paths in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlet-3.0

I need to add `/api` and `/stat` as my two context paths. I already added `/api` for the application using `server.servlet.context-path=/api`.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?, couldn't you just have the context path / and the two subpaths /api and /stats ?

Comment: @karelss. I used subpaths for different services like ```/api/user``` ```/api/content```. These endpoints are using jwt auth mechanism. I need to expose ```/stat``` in basic auth. Can show me a way of doing that.

Comment: @anuradha151 have u found the solution? I have same problem. Spring Security can config two url pattern to match, with each url pattern, u can use sperate filter to auth. But, in my scenario, I want two context pathes to fit all request mappings in all controllers, security way seems not work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the server.servlet.context-path will affect all your endpoints, but you can specify a different @RequestMapping in each controller class.
So if you remove the server.servlet.context-path, you will use the root context path ("/"), and then setting  "/api" & "/stat" on your controllers should work.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. But the requirement is to add basic auth endpoints in a new context-path. Currently I use jwt token authentication for ```/api``` endpoints.

Comment: Maybe this can help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706291/spring-multiple-authentication-methods-for-different-api-endpoints