# Oauth2Login only for certain uris

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have this Spring Security configuration:

```
@Bean
  SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
            .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
                    .pathMatchers("/hub/public/**").permitAll()
                    .anyExchange().authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::jwt)
            .build();
  }
```

I want to trigger the oauth2Login redirection only to some specific uris. The rest of the uris should get HTTP 401 response in case of missing Authorization.

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: You can create multiple `SecurityWebFilterChains`. Take a look at this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706291/spring-multiple-authentication-methods-for-different-api-endpoints

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Webflux